# lwjgl freezes on creation of Font object

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am making a simple game of snake, because I can, and I stumbled across an interesting bug. I am trying to use Slick-Util to draw some text on the screen, but whenever I try to create a font object the game freezes. [Here](https://gist.github.com/thislooksfun/63a9d42b122a261ba99c#file-snakegame-java-L154-L161) is my code. The highlighted section only prints 'a' once.

```
package tlf.snake.main;


import tlf.snake.main.game.helper.Pos;
import tlf.snake.main.game.input.Input;

import java.awt.Font;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWWindowPosCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWWindowSizeCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWvidmode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext;

import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.glfwSetCallback;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

/**
 * @author thislooksfun
 */
public class SnakeGame
{
    private static final Game game = new Game();

    private int WIDTH = game.gameWidth*15;
    private int HEIGHT = game.gameHeight*15;

    private static final int MINWIDTH = game.gameWidth*10;
    private static final int MINHEIGHT = game.gameHeight*10;

    private Pos lastPos;

    private int size = 10;
    private boolean resized = false;

    private boolean running = false;

    private long window;

    private static SnakeGame instance;

    public TrueTypeFont font;

    public SnakeGame()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    private void init()
    {
        if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing");
            //TODO handle
            return;
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "NEAT Snake", NULL, NULL);

        if (window == NULL) {
            System.out.println("Error creating window");
            //TODO handle
            return;
        }

        ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - WIDTH) / 2, (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - HEIGHT) / 2);
        initCallbacks();
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        GLContext.createFromCurrent();

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        setOrtho();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        initFonts();

        running = true;
        resized = true;

        game.start();
    }

    private void initCallbacks()
    {
        glfwSetCallback(window, GLFWWindowSizeCallback(new GLFWWindowSizeCallback.SAM()
        {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int width, int height)
            {
                resized = true;
                WIDTH = width;
                HEIGHT = height;

                if (width < MINWIDTH && height >= MINHEIGHT) {
                    glfwSetWindowSize(window, MINWIDTH, height);
                    glfwSetWindowPos(window, lastPos.x-10, lastPos.y);
                } else if (width >= MINWIDTH && height < MINHEIGHT) {
                    glfwSetWindowSize(window, width, MINHEIGHT);
                    glfwSetWindowPos(window, lastPos.x-10, lastPos.y);
                } else if (width < MINWIDTH && height < MINHEIGHT) {
                    glfwSetWindowSize(window, MINWIDTH, MINHEIGHT);
                    glfwSetWindowPos(window, lastPos.x-10, lastPos.y);
                } else
                    lastPos = getWindowPos();

                render();
                setOrtho();
            }
        }));

        glfwSetCallback(window, GLFWWindowPosCallback(new GLFWWindowPosCallback.SAM()
        {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int xpos, int ypos)
            {
                lastPos = new Pos(xpos, ypos);
            }
        }));

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, new Input());
    }

    private Pos getWindowPos()
    {
        IntBuffer xbuf = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);
        IntBuffer ybuf = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);
        glfwGetWindowPos(window, xbuf, ybuf);

        return new Pos(xbuf.get(0), ybuf.get(0));
    }

    private void setOrtho()
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    private void initFonts()
    {
        System.out.println("a");
        Font awtFont = new Font("Default", Font.BOLD, 24);
        System.out.println("a");
        font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, true);
        System.out.println("a");
    }

    public void start()
    {
        init();
        while (running)
        {
            update();
            render();
            if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void update()
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        game.tick();
    }

    private void render()
    {
        if (resized) {
            setOrtho();
            calcTileSize();
            resized = false;
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        game.render();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    public static SnakeGame instance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    private void calcTileSize()
    {
        int sh, sw;
        sh = (int)Math.floor((1.0f*HEIGHT)/game.gameHeight);
        sw = (int)Math.floor((1.0f*WIDTH)/game.gameWidth);

        size = sh > sw ? sw : sh;
    }

    public int tileSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
-tlf

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, slick isn't being updated anymore. You seem to be using LWJGL3, which is a complete rewrite of LWJGL2 (which, I believe, slick was made with).

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz: There isn't a stacktrace - it doesn't crash, it just hangs.

Comment: @JackWhiteIII: Maybe, but it doesn't even get that far. It only gets to line [157](https://gist.github.com/thislooksfun/63a9d42b122a261ba99c#file-snakegame-java-L157), which is a default java class.

Comment: @thislooksfun all I can suggest right now is trying to load the awt font somewhere else, for example before all the LWJGL stuff. I might look into it later when I'm on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with another font like "Arial" or "Serif"? I guess "Default" is not a valid name for a font in windows.

Try something like this:

```
Font awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24);
font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);
```

Or, if you have the `.ttf` file try something like this:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("anotherfont.ttf");
    Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream);
    awtFont = awtFont2.deriveFont(24f);
    font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont2, false);      
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I was using `"Times New Roman"` to begin with. I changed it because I checked the code and "Default" was listed there. Also, I'm on OS X.

Comment: @thislooksfun Maybe "Lucida Grande" will work, or Helvetica, which apparently is the OS X default font.

Comment: @thislooksfun or try to get the "default.ttf" and load it manually, here http://onscripter.unclemion.com/pub/default-font.zip you can download a free version font

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason, if you try to call `new Font(...)` ***after*** calling glfwCreateWindow, it hangs indefinitely. Creating the `Font` object *before* creating the window works just fine though.

Credit goes to @JackWhiteIII for suggesting that.

EDIT: [I found out why! (and how to fix it)](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/68)

Comment: I'm glad that your problem is solved. I'd love to know why it's like that, though.

Comment: So would I. I see no reason for it to happen. O_o

Comment: @JackWhiteIII I found out why! Post edited to reflect.

Comment: Good to know how to get rid of the problem so that developing on windows and deploying for Mac works well. Thank you for showing me!

Comment: @JackWhiteIII no problem! Thanks for suggesting the fix that lead to that. :)